# Changing the WooCommerce Featured Product Style?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, wordpress-featured-image

I have been trying to figure this out for hours with no luck.

Right now the WooCommerce Featured Product widget displays the products vertically. Im wanting to get the Featured Products to display side-by-side(horizontally).

Ive looked everywhere I could think of and I just cant find what I need to edit to make this happen.

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fix the width of each product and use css property

```
float:left;
```

to show featured products horizontally.